# alternative to findViewById() in classes other than activities (Android Studios)

Tags: java, android, view

I'm working on an android game that will have several levels and since each level will have the same code, I thought it would be good idea to create that code in a separate class and then using object of that class to use the code. However, all of my current code inside the main activity uses findViewById() to refer to different view in my app but I'm unfortunately unable to use this function outside of an activity inside just a normal class file. Are there any alternative ways of referring to views that I may be able to use in other classes?

Thanks

Comment: What does this question have to do with Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to do so, maybe you can pass the view itself as parameter but be careful to check if this view is in the correct context and if the view exists in the current screen to avoid some null pointer exceptions. 
It's difficult to decide if this solution can even work without seeing your code